# CLJS: CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Feature should be a keyword

Tags: clojurescript

I get this error whenever I have some code like this in a `.cljc` file. I couldn't find any answer when I searched for it.

```
(defn foo
  []
  #?(:cljs
      (f "1")
      (g "2")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that in `#?(:cljs ...)` or `#?(:clj ...)` we can only specify one form.

Therefore, for multiple functions we can use `do` for example.

```
(defn foo
  []
  #?(:cljs
      (do (f "1")
          (g "2")))
```

Edit: 9/3/21

applies not only to functions but more generally to forms

Eg. (does not work)

```
(try
  (something...)
  (catch #(:clj Exception e (error-stuff...)
         #(:cljs :default e (error-stuff...)
```

should be

```
(try
  (something...)
  #(:clj (catch Exception e (clj-error-stuff e)))
  #(:cljs (catch :default e (cljs-errors-stuff e)))
```